VSTACK doesn't pile up dynamic ranges
My question is simple: when I replace a range (array) with the corresponding VSTACK function, my formula returns weird results.

I am working on a financial model that I have simplified for this post. I have the returns of an asset, month by month, that I want to compound (that is, I give the initial and ending month of my calculation). In the example given, I want to know the total return from month 1 to 2, from month 2 to 4 and from month 1 to 5.
The "from to" months appear in a range. When I use the range directly in my formula, the results are correct, as it is proven below in the check range.
However, if I use the VSTACK function, the function does not work, it gives incorrect returns. It seems to take into account only the "from" month, without paying any attention to the "to" month at all.
It is the first time that I encounter a problem like this one with VSTACK.
The problem that I have is that in my model, the range of "from...to" months expands to the right, so that I cannot use the formula based on the simple range.
I am not obliged to use the VSTACK function, any function that works on dynamic arrays is fine for me, provided that it works, of course.
My questions are:
1- why do you think the VSTACK function is not working in my model?
2- what alternative formulas could I use instead that works on dynamic array (that expand).
Formula that doesn't work:
=BYCOL(VSTACK(J3#;J4#);LAMBDA(c;PRODUCT(1+INDEX(C4:G4;;SEQUENCE(1;INDEX(c;2)-INDEX(c;1)+1;INDEX(c;1))))-1))

Formula that works, but it is not exactly what I need:
=BYCOL(J3:L4;LAMBDA(c;PRODUCT(1+INDEX(C4:G4;;SEQUENCE(1;INDEX(c;2)-INDEX(c;1)+1;INDEX(c;1))))-1))

I am using the International setting for Spain.
Thank you
I have proved that VSTACK does not work by using a simple fixed range instead, as it is shown on the picture above.
The result expected is also shown in the picture.
I have simplified my model to the maximum before posting my question.
My question resembles a little the one whose title is "VSTACK (and TEXTSPLIT) on dynamic ranges" but I do not think that the problem is exactly the same.

Put @ in front of the three INDEXES inside the SEQUENCE:
=BYCOL(VSTACK(J3#,J4#),LAMBDA(c,PRODUCT(1+INDEX(C4:G4,,SEQUENCE(1,@INDEX(c,2)-@INDEX(c,1)+1,@INDEX(c,1))))-1))

REMEMBER that you need to replace the , with ; for your locale.


It works perfectly !!!
My formula contains 4 INDEX function, only 3 of which are inside a SEQUENCE function. I can see that I should put the "@" before the INDEX functions that are inside the SEQUENCE function.
I had tried to debug my formula with Excel Labs, but it tells me that it cannot debug it as of now. I suppose that in a future version it will.
I suppose that the "@" is necessary to force "implicit intersection" , but in my opinion, those two internal calls to INDEX should have returned a single value, because the calculation is done BYCOL. Am I wrong?

@vsoler it is something I cannot explain the why it is needed.  It is something we have come up against many times when nesting INDEX inside LAMBDA.  Again, I do not know why.

This question is duplicate. This has been raised thrice, was suggested to use @ --> Implicit Intersection Operator or INDEX() function. The alternative way: =BYCOL(VSTACK(J3#,J4#),LAMBDA(c,LET(d, INDEX(c,1,1), PRODUCT(1+INDEX(C4:G4,,SEQUENCE(1,INDEX(c,2,1)-d+1,d)))-1))) --> here the INDEX(c,r,column) what it does for each column it will take the top most cell of the left side of the array. the column is fixed as 1 if it would have been row wise then --> INDEX(x,1,c) since you are using an array, you are asking the BYCOL() to check for each column top most left side cell continued

So when it moves from {J3;J4} to {K3;K4} it will take 2 for the start and 4 for the end similarly for others in the array. also it is suggested to OP @vsoler to use one single account and to respond to their other posts they have posted Un responded.

Hello Mayukh,
I've been using StackOverflow for several years now, and I am very satisfied with the answers that I get in response. But for a reason that I do not know, it was impossible for me this time to log-in into StackOverflow, and the only workaround that I found was to create a new account.  I thought that, somehow, my past questions had been deleted from the site, and creating a new account was the only solution that I found. Now that you mention that I have 2 accounts, I am a bit surprised that StackOverflow allowed me to create two different accounts using the same email address.

For me, having two accounts is a mess, and if only it was possible to merge them, I would do it right away. Additionally, with the new account that I have created, it seems as though I cannot rate the comments that I have received, which I find most useful. If you have any suggestions that might help, I am more than willing to hear them. And, to be honest, I am a little embarrassed by the inconvenience that I may have caused you.

This is more an issue of function selection. MAP is better suited for this task, because it does not require the help of INDEX or @ to reference and convert array objects (TYPE 64) to numeric values (TYPE 1).
With the start months (s) in range J3# and the end months (e) in range J4#, the formula structure of MAP would simply be:
=MAP(J3#;J4#;LAMBDA(s;e;PRODUCT(1+INDEX(C4:G4;;SEQUENCE(1;e-s+1;s)))-1))

Your original BYCOL formula did not work as expected with VSTACK because of the differences in data types between range references and array objects; however, a complete explanation is two-fold...
SEQUENCE:
When an array object (TYPE 64) is passed to any one of the SEQUENCE function's arguments, it will be interpreted as an attempt to generate an array of arrays (not supported). As a result, only the first value will be returned. For example, =SEQUENCE(1;{3};2) will only return a single value of 2, because the [columns] argument received an array object {3} and the [start] argument was set to 2.
INDEX:
When using INDEX on a single column or row of data (vector), the [column_num] argument can be omitted; however, the data type of the value returned will differ when referencing a physical range vs an array object. For example, working with your sample screenshot, =INDEX(K3:K4;2) will return 4 (TYPE 1), whereas =INDEX(VSTACK(K3;K4);2) will return {4} (TYPE 64), because VSTACK(K3;K4) will evaluate to {2;4}, which is an array object. To ensure the value returned is TYPE 1, simply specify both the row_num and [column_num] arguments of INDEX. You can verify this with the TYPE function:

=TYPE(INDEX(K3:K4;2)) = 1 (number)
=TYPE(INDEX(VSTACK(K3;K4);2)) = 64 (array)
=TYPE(INDEX(VSTACK(K3;K4);2;1)) = 1 (number)
=BYCOL(J3#:J4;LAMBDA(c;TYPE(INDEX(c;2)))) = 1 | 1 | 1
(numbers)
=BYCOL(VSTACK(J3#;J4#);LAMBDA(c;TYPE(INDEX(c;2)))) =
64 | 64 | 64 (arrays)
=BYCOL(VSTACK(J3#;J4#);LAMBDA(c;TYPE(INDEX(c;2;1)))) =
1 | 1 | 1 (numbers)
=MAP(J3#;J4#;LAMBDA(s;e;TYPE(s))) = 1 | 1 | 1 (numbers)
=MAP(J3#;J4#;LAMBDA(s;e;TYPE(e))) = 1 | 1 | 1 (numbers)

This explanation was provided as a direct response to the question. However, as stated above, the entire issue can be avoided by using the MAP function instead of BYCOL.

One exception to the rule: when using INDEX with a single element array object, you can safely omit the [column num] argument, e.g. =TYPE(INDEX({5};1)) will return 1 (number). For more information, please see: Curious behaviour of BYROW-SEQUENCE..., which was tailored for single element array objects resulting from BYROW over a single column vector.

Very clear answer, it goes really in depth, thank you
